# How to use mechanize to enter username and password

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to use mechanize to scrape a website that requires me to log in. Here is the start of me code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#scrape the admissions part of SAFE

import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://url')

# View available forms
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

This gives me

```
<POST https://userstuff application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(lt=LT-227363-Ja4QpRvdxrbQF0nb7XcR2jQDydH43s) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(execution=e1s1) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(_eventId=submit) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(username=)>
  <PasswordControl(password=)>
  <SubmitButtonControl(submit=) (readonly)>
  <CheckboxControl(warn=[on])>>
```

> How can I now enter the username and password?

I tried

```
# Select the first (index zero) form 
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['username'] = 'username'
br.form['password'] = 'password'

# Login
br.submit()
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `br.submit()`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, sorry. I accidentally missed that from my question.

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: Can you provide the html of the form you're trying to submit? You need to confirm that the form input names are actually `username` and `password`

Comment: @user3195487 I am really new to this but does the output I gave below "This gives me" not answer that?

Comment: @user3195487,  it is in  the question body

Comment: @user3195487 The main part of the html is https://bpaste.net/show/1d9cfaeb727c (lightly edited)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I pasted the main part of the form just above.

Comment: The form id is `fm1` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495313/mechanize-select-form-using-id, you can try using that in case you are selecting the wrong from, if that does not work then there is something else going on and without seeing the actual link it is going to be hard to say what is wrong

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oh actually I think there just one more screen to get through! This one has this form  <POST https://url application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(choice=sso) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(target=/Teaching/Resources/) (readonly)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=Choose Single Sign-on) (readonly)>>  . I just need to click submit I believe.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham all working now.. could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @eleanora, you can add an answer with what worked and get some rep for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end this worked for me

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#scraper

import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('url1')

# View available forms
for f in br.forms():
    if f.attrs['id'] == 'fm1':
        br.form = f
        break

# User credentials
br.form['username'] = 'password'
br.form['password'] = 'username'

# Login
br.submit()

#Now we need to confirm again

br.open('https://url2')

# Select the first (index zero) form 
br.select_form(nr=0)

# Login
br.submit()

print(br.open('https:url2').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the html form rather than what mechanize gives you. Below is an example of a form I've tried to fill out in the past.

```
<input type="text" name="user_key" value="">
<input type="password" name="user_password">
```

Below is the code I use to log into that website using the form above

```
# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(False) 
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://www.website.com/login')

#select the first form
br.select_form(nr=0)

#user credentials
br['user_key'] = 'myusername@gmail.com'
br['user_password'] = 'mypassword'

# Login
br.submit()

link = 'http://www.website.com/url_i_want_to_scrape'

br.open(link)
response = br.response().read()
print response
```

Your issue could be that you're either choosing the wrong form giving the incorrect field names

Comment: I'm showing an example of a time when I faced the same issue and a way to resolve it. Of course the websites aren't the same but the technique can be used in his/her case as well

Comment: I get AttributeError: type object 'CookieJar' has no attribute 'LWPCookieJar' error when I am using this. Although I imported cookielib(now called cookiejar). Any ideas?